# jQuery: Remove all elements after the first n elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something close to this:

```
<div class="batman-pictures">
    <a><img /></a>
    <a><img /></a>
    <a><img /></a>
    <a><img /></a>
    <a><img /></a>
    <a><img /></a>
</div>
```

I don't know how many `<a><img /></a>` that will be generated (I am fetching them from an API), and I want to delete all elements after the first three(n) `<a><img /></a>`. How can I do this in jQuery?

Comment: `$('.batman-pictures a:gt(2)').remove()`

Comment: [`:gt()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/).

Comment: @Tushar: Thanks! Great solution, but accepted the other answer that also worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(".batman-pictures a:nth-child(3)").nextAll().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nth selector. https://jsfiddle.net/j5cthunu/

```
$(".batman-pictures a:nth-child(n+4)").remove();
```